# Плагины для eclipse

Tags: python, javascript, html, плагин, css

Есть надобность в использование javascript, html, css, python, стоит ли поискать для этого дела плагин к eclipse. Кто использовал, расскажите о проблемах, которые встретились вкратце :-) Заранее благодарю.

Comment: Последнее время все прихожу к выводу что не надо использовать чудо-комбайны, вроде emacs, а использовать специализированные инструменты. Ничего универсального ведь не существует :-) 
Попробую использовать то что вы предложили, позже оценю =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А чего искать-то, когда фавориты давно известны? :)

- [PyDev](http://pydev.org/)
- [Aptana Studio](http://www.aptana.com/)

---

Проблемы у каждого свои. Так чтобы какие-то глобальные недостатки указанных пакетов… да, вроде бы, нет :).

Answer (score 3):

Я думаю, проще использовать [PyCharm](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/): удобный дебаггер, UI-интеграция с контролем версий (Subversion, CVS, Git, TFC, etc), интеграция для юнит-тестирования, поддержка GAE, работа с HTML, CSS и JavaScript как и во всех IDE на платформе IDEA, возможность работы с удаленными сорцами (например, по Ssh). Но это, наверное, для привыкших работать в IDEA.