# Среда разработки для python под windows

Tags: python, windows, ide

Подскажите хорошую среду разработки для python для windows. С автокомплитом, подсветкой, средствами рефакторинга и возможностью запуска на выполнение прямо в среде.

Попробовал Editra, SPE
Не впечатлило. Может есть какой-нить мануал по настройке какого-то крутого блокнота. Хотя конечно лучше всё-таки среду разработки

P.S. только не нужно кидать мне ссылку на вот эту страницу [PythonEditors](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonEditors)

Comment: И да, PyCharm есть в том списке ;)

Comment: Не буду создавать отдельный вопрос, задам тут: какой редактор имеет portable-версию? Желательно, чтоб полностью сохранялся функционал...

Comment: Хм Ну вы определитесь уже. Вам шаш.. нормальное IDE или или портабельную угэшечку. Из таких есть PyScripter, не умеет почти ничего по сравнению со своими большими братьями, но для простых проектов сойдет.

Comment: Мне нужна портабельная НЕугешечка :D Окей. попробую, спасибо.

Comment: PyCharm не портабельна(по крайней мере я прецедентов не видел), а следовательно больше не остается кошерных IDE. Как-то так ;)

Comment: Скажу пару слов за PyDev.

Плагин неплохой, но настоящей конкуренции с PyCharm не выдерживает. Использовать можно только при фанатичной преданности Eclipse.

Comment: Очень удачно я нашел. Подробная статья о редакторах для Python
Рекомендую к прочтению: https://use-web.ru/news.php?id=25&tid=3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PyCharm от Jetbrains единственная достойная IDE для Python. Да, дорого, а что делать. Если не хочется платить, а что такое совесть давно забыто, то кряк найти труда не составит.

Comment: http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/PYH/PyCharm+Feature+Comparison+Matrix Говорит само за себя

Comment: Это точно, лучше pycharm нет

Comment: Естественно PyCharm. Лидер безоговорочный.

Answer (score 2):

Конечно [PyCharm](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) от jetbrains. Сначала пользовался аптаной, после открытия для себя pycharm забыл эту хрень как страшный сон.

Достаточно неплохой и удобный интерфейс, нормальный автокомплит, есть рефакторинг, всякие консоли встроенные, удобно запускать тесты, удобная работа с системой контроля версий, всяческие умные подсказки по коду, нормальный дебаггер, миллион удобных горячих клавиш, которые превращают разработку в удовольствие.

А уже если иметь дело с django, то вообще равных нет, даже отладку шаблонов джанго прикрутили в последней версии, а также встроенные в интерфейс инструменты для удобной работы с джанго проектами, плюс к этому всему дополнительно удобные редакторы html/css/django templates c zen coding.

В общем с моей субъективной точки зрения эклипсы/аптаны и рядом с этим не валялись по удобству использования и интерфейсу.

Answer (score 1):

Ок, тогда кину ссылку на [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/2274/плагины-для-eclipse](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/2274/%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-eclipse). Не факт, что ответ исчерпывающий, но посмотрите там. =)

Answer (score 1):

я бы посоветовал посмотреть на http://www.reinteract.org/ (правда на данную минуту у  них сайт не совсем верно работает).
Это не IDE в прямом смысле слова. Это такой полигон для испытаний. Мне как раз это то, что нужно для написания небольших кусков кода (до нескольких сотен строк). Можно запускать куски кода, отладить, а потом просто скопировать в файл в готовый проект.

Comment: ну для этого можно и IDLE использовать, а мне нужна такая среда, в которой я смогу открыть большой OpenSource проект и мне будет удобно работать с ним там

Comment: Это лучше чем IDLE. Значительно лучше.
а большой проект лучше открывать в том, что в чем есть привычка работать.

Answer (score 1):

PyDev для Eclipse

Answer (score 1):

поддеживаю PyDev для Eclipse, можно попробовать SciTe неплохой такой блокнот.